# Is appending a double quote at the end of an input query a valid XSS prevention method?

Tags: xss

I was wondering if appending a double quote at the end of a query is considered a valid XSS filter. Let's say we have a search function and I entered:

```
"><script>alert('hi')</script>
```

If I look at the source of the resulting query I will see the following:

```
<input name="search" type="text" value=""><script>alert('hi')</script>">
```

The double quote will be appended automatically at the end of my query.

Assuming that the filter also scrubs out the null char, and HTML comments `<!--`, would this be an effective XSS filter or is this just wishful thinking?

Comment: What html tag are you injecting into?

Comment: sorry my code did not show properly, thanks to Lekensteyn for editing :)

Comment: the alert box above should execute...  did you try this before posting?

Comment: Ok, now I got it to work :) And thank you for the reply as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of no condition in which this would mitigate XSS. 
If an attacker supplies `<script>alert(1)</script>`  the result will be:
`<script>alert(1)</script>"` which will still execute.

Further more,  an attacker can just comment out the double quote in javascript:
`alert(1)//"`

You don't need an html comment to build valid html:

```
<input name="search" type="text" value=""><script>alert('hi')</script><input name="inject">
```

You should read the [XSS prevention cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet),  XSS is extremely common and you shouldn't come up with home-brew solutions to well known problems.